# How I can download resources from internet and report that immediately (with max concurrent tasks at same time) in c# (winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, task-parallel-library, webclient

I'm making an app that show some data collected from web in a windows form, today I have to wait sequentially to download all data before show them, how I can do it in parallel in a limited queue (with max concurrent tasks executing) to show result refreshing a datagridview while they are downloaded?

what I have today is a method

```
    internal async Task<string> RequestDataAsync(string uri)
    {
        var wb = new System.Net.WebClient(); //                 
        var sourceAsync = wb.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);
        string data = await sourceAsync;
        return data;
    }
```

that I put on a foreach() and after it ends, parse data to a list of custom object, then convert that object to a DataTable and bind the datagridview to that.

I not sure if the best way is using LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler from example on https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx (that I not sure how can report to grid each time a resource is downlaoded) or there is a best way to do this.

I not like to start all tasks at same time, because sometimes can be that I have to request 100 downlads at same time, and I like that it will be executed for example 10 tasks at same time maximum.

I know that it is a question that involves control concurrent tasks and report while download that, but not sure what is best nowadays to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't often recommend [my book](http://stephencleary.com/book/), but I think it would help you.

Concurrent asynchrony is done via `Task.WhenAll` (recipe 2.4 in my book):

```
List<string> uris = ...;
var tasks = uris.Select(uri => RequestDataAsync(uri));
string[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

To limit concurrency, use a `SemaphoreSlim` (recipe 11.5 in my book):

```
List<string> uris = ...;
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(10);
var tasks = uris.Select(async uri =>
{
  await semaphore.WaitAsync();
  try { await RequestDataAsync(uri); }
  finally { semaphore.Release(); }
});
string[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

To process data as it arrives, introduce another `async` method (recipe 2.6 in my book):

```
List<string> uris = ...;
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(10);
var tasks = uris.Select(async uri =>
{
  await semaphore.WaitAsync();
  try { await RequestAndProcessDataAsync(uri); }
  finally { semaphore.Release(); }
});
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

async Task RequestAndProcessDataAsync(string uri)
{
  var data = await RequestDataAsync(uri);
  var myObject = Parse(data);
  _listBoundToDataTable.Add(myObject);
}
```

Comment: thanks you so much, I really was reading the last two days about threading, concurrency, async/await and still cannot glue all the parts correctly, I will get your book to understand better what is going on, now I have to test this code and see if that do the work :) 
 thanks for your faster answer, you rocks